# How to write a extension method to check empty of white spaces dart

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods

Can Any one explain me how to check empty of white spaces.

```
extension StringExtensions on String {

  bool isNullOrEmpty() => this == null || isEmpty;

 // check empty of white spaces


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `contains` method or you can check it with regexp, here an example

```
extension StringExtensions on String {
  bool get isNullOrEmpty {
    bool _hasSpace = RegExp(r'\s').hasMatch(this);
    //  bool _hasSpace = this.contains(' ');

    return this == null || isEmpty || _hasSpace;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [isNullOrWhitespace](https://pub.dev/documentation/dart_extensions/latest/dart_extensions/StringExtensions/isNullOrWhiteSpace.html) implementation in [dart_extensions](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_extensions).

The implementation is a bit convoluted, but it does the following:

```
extension StringExtensions on String {
  bool get isNullOrWhiteSpace {
    var length = (this?.split('') ?? []).where((x) => x == ' ').length;
    return length == (this?.length ?? 0) || this.isEmptyOrNull;
  }

  bool get isEmptyOrNull => this == null || this!.isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35588124)

Comment: @DavidMaze I added more detail.